# ¿Qué es la salida del buffer en php? o en programación en general

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo php con el [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) y estaba leyendo sobre las etiquetas de apertura y cierre (es el enlace que compartí al comienzo de este párrafo). El manual se aconseja que es mejor omitir la etiqueta de cierre cuando el archivo `.php` contiene solo código php para evitar saltos de línea o espacios en blanco no deseado, porque eso puede causar que php comience la salida del bufer cuando no se pensaba enviar ninguna salida por parte del programador.

¿Se refiere el manual por salida del buffer al momento en el que se esta escribiendo el resultado del script (el html que queda escrito luego de que php computa las expresiones y ejecuta las sentencias) para mandarlo al cliente http?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El búfer de salida es un método para decirle al motor PHP que retenga los datos de salida antes de enviarlos al navegador.

Por defecto PHP trabaja **sin almacenamiento de salida**, enviando los datos de salida al navegador por partes, en la medida en que el script se procesa.

Pero puede haber contextos en los que te interese trabajar **con almacenamiento de salida** (PHP dispone de [varias funciones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.outcontrol.php) para ello). En este caso, toda la salida se almacena en una variable y se envían al navegador como una sola pieza al final del script.

Hay otros casos en los que, trabajando con o sin buffer de salida, te interese retener la salida antes de un determinado punto del script PHP, por ejemplo:

- Estás construyendo un contenido completo y concatenándolo en una variable para hacer `echo` de esa variable al final
- Quieres recoger contenido desde una clase o función u otro archivo incluido y enviar cabeceras. Cuando envías cabeceras no puede haber salida del buffer antes de las cabeceras
- El cliente espera un JSON/XML que sea válido y ese JSON/XML es construido recorriendo varias partes del código en las que no puede haber ninguna otra salida que rompería la estructura del JSON/XML haciéndolo inválido.

Cuando el Manual de PHP dice: *porque eso puede causar que php comience la salida del bufer cuando no se pensaba enviar ninguna salida por parte del programador*, quiere decir que una etiqueta de cierre puesta sin necesidad podría causar una salida que dañaría la intención de no sacar nada por el buffer hasta un determinado momento, de forma explícita, haciendo `echo`, `print` o de otro modo.

Esto es así porque si después del bloque de cierre hay espacios en blanco, saltos de línea, problemas de BOM, etc, ese contenido se interpretará como salida, causando problemas.

Para más detalles puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2832010/5587982) de Stackoverflow en inglés y sus respuestas.

#### Otros enlaces para profundizar

- [What is PHP Output Buffering?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-php-output-buffering)
- [PHP Output Buffering](https://phppot.com/php/php-output-buffering/)
- [What is PHP Output Buffering?](https://notlaura.com/output-buffering/)